# React keep ref in state, good or bad practise? How to get ref on some DOM element from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, reference, react-props, forwarding-reference

Hello I would like to ask, is it "good" (ok) or bad practise to store ref in parents state?

What I need:

- Lets assume we have parent component WRAPPER.
- Inside WRAPPER I have 2 components, ComponentA and ComponentB
- ComponentA has some important element which I have to reference
- ComponentB, when its rendered has to render some attributes from the reference from ComponentA

Unfortunately, ComponentA is null and does not exist when the application starts. This component is initialized dynamically based on something else. If I create the ref and pass it through props in WRAPPER component, unfortunately it remains null. In ComponentA (when it is initialized) I can successfully reach the reference, unfortunately WRAPPER does not know about its initialization.

That is why I am thinking about instead of forwarding this ref, I think about forwarding state in which I would like to keep the reference. In ComponentA receive the ref and set the Ref. This is how WRAPPER will recognize the ref changed and than I should pass the ref to ComponentB in which I will be able to get the attributes.

Is there anything else (better solution) to solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

store a ref into a state is totally alright if you need some re-render based on that one

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not sure as it is not adviced to store references in redux store (if I understood that correctly because of reference is not immutable and serialized object) so I was not sure if the same advices are in case of storing it in state as redux store is only global state...

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** use [contexts](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext) to separate state, hooks, and elements' lifecycles:

```js
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ComponentA />
      <ComponentB />
    </div>
  );
};

export const AppContext = createContext(null);

const Wrapper = (props) => {
  // HOC with context
  const [data, setData] = useState("Nothing typed yet.");

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ data, setData }}>
      <App {...props} />
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ComponentA = () => {
  const { setData } = useContext(AppContext);
  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setData(event.target.value);
    },
    [setData]
  );
  return <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />;
};

const ComponentB = () => {
  const { data } = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <h1>{data}</h1>
    </>
  );
};
```

Check it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-matan-wkzlsk?file=/src/App.js).

**NL;PR:** In React, state refers (no pun intended) to data values that can be serialized. Refs and other functions and other program references cannot be serialized. Doing so, breaks hydration.

Since both can be used as props, it causes confusion.